# How to strip sheath off outdoor cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, tools, safety, 120-240v

I am looking for a way to remove the protective sheath from a length of multicore mains electrical cable. It's rated for outdoor use and is VERY strong. Without butchering my fingers; trying to fine cut it with a utility knife and without cutting into the hot wire insulation (and exposing the bare copper) in the process. I've already made 4 such errors and inflicted 2 knife cuts.
[image: stabbystab]

Comment: So; what exactly is it that you're doing, or wanting to do? Take care.

Answer (score 1):

I've usually had good luck with a decent quality wire stripper with NM sheathing cutters.  After you clamp down on the cable you just have to pull a lot harder than on NM to break the last bits of sheathing that go around the ground.  I have something similar to this:

[image]

<sup>Image from Home Depot, does not constitute a recommendation for the vendor, the manufacturer, or the model pictured.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Stripping UF is a bear.  The usual NM strippers won't work for me, you'll nick the wires.  Luckily, there is a stripper made for the task:

[Ideal Industries UF Stripper 45-235](http://www.idealind.com/prodDetail.do?prodId=45-235&div=3&l1=wire_strippers)

[image: Ideal Industries UF Stripper 45-235]

Unfortunately, it isn't cheap.  Costs less than losing a finger though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure as to why you're doing a lot of stripping on wire you apparently want to keep using, but no matter.

I use an olfa brand knife (box cutter with a blade you can extend a variable distance) with the blade out 1/16".

[image: Olfa knife]

You can grip the nose of the knife between thumb and forefinger and use your fingers to ride the crown of the wire. Try to set the wire on something solid so your other hand isn't in the way. Once you've scored the sheathing, you can usually pull it apart either by hand or with pliers.

Answer (score -2):

### AUTOMATIC WIRE STRIPPER/CUTTER/CRIMPER

PART NO. K4001
[image: KINCROME K4001 - Stock Photo]

---

### FEATURES:

• Ratcheting Handle With Built-In Guillotine-Style Wire-Cutter.
• Strong, Firm, Adjustable, Multi-Point Vice-Grip Jaws.
• Linear Wire Stripping Motion. (Won't snap Cables).
• Strips 24-10 Awg (0.2-6.0 mm^2) Insulated Wire.
• Crimp 22-10 Awg (0.5-6.0 mm^2) Insulated Terminals.
• Crimp 22-10 Awg (0.5-6.0 mm^2) Non-Insulated Terminals.
• Crimp 07-08 mm Ignition Terminals.

---

[image: KINCROME K4001 - Cuts & Crimp]
[image: KINCROME K4001 - Grip & Strip]
[image: KINCROME K4001 - Strip & Quit]

Comment: Haven't finished this post yet. Will be adding more.

Comment: Looks a whole lot like an ad to me, although your rep on other SE sites suggests otherwise. You might consider taking the promotional language out.

Comment: @DanielGriscom An ad? Promotional language? I don't really see how that's fair. I'm not on the company's payroll if that's what you mean. Someone asked for a product recommendation. This is a product that I personally own, use and recommend. I'll say it again; I recommend this exact product, model, manufacturer, brand, and whatever else. Why? Well.. Because it's good. Also, I provided some specs.. FYI: I own a lot of tools. I had a few others to recommend as well, I just haven't gotten around to adding them yet.

Comment: As reviewers, we're on the lookout for spam (i.e. unsolicited advertisements where the poster is part of the company and doesn't reveal his linkage). Your post looks a lot like spam, although again I doubt it is because you aren't new to the site and have done good work elsewhere. I didn't downvote it; why do you think other people did?

Comment: So, "fair" isn't part of it; I'm just stating the facts, and others have reacted the same way (again: note the downvotes). If you added a "This tool has worked well for me because..." paragraph at the top, I bet people would react better to it.

Comment: I'll say it again. Someone asked for a product recommendation. So I gave one. It's not spam.

Comment: I know that your post was truly not spam, and was meant to be helpful. But why do you think it got downvotes, while three other similar posts didn't? It's because by the standards of Stack Exchange, it looks like spam, posted by the manufacturer. Two changes would fix this: removing the detailed promotional language (e.g. "Ratcheting Handle With Built-In Guillotine-Style Wire-Cutter"), and adding a personal paragraph at the top saying why you've found this to be a good solution to the original poster's question. If you don't care, then OK; I won't be flagging it. I'm just trying to help.